# SSRS Scheduled Reports - No HTTP Log entries

Tags: http, logging, reporting-services, schedule

I'm looking to get some stats on the parameter retrieval from the HTTP Logs in production. We already get them when we normally execute the reports via the Report Manager or via a url. But when running the report via a schedule (we have them set up in production for the warm ups) nothing is logging....

We also tried a report via schedule in our test env and got no http entries.. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scheduled reports run as SQL Server Agents jobs, so I wouldn't be at all surprised if they don't hit ReportServer, hence no HTTP logs.

Have you looked into querying the [execution log](http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2011/2/6/querying-the-report-server-execution-log.html)? It's got quite detailed information, and will contain entries for every report execution.

Comment: We use fiddler, the http logs and the exection Log (view) to map performance. :)
Thank you for your answer.